# Batch import for collection administrator in dspace 6.0

Tags: dspace

I an working on a project that requires batch import of items by simple archive format even by collection administrators. I have looked in source code of dspace. Nowhere i am able to find which class is used for batch importing and how to change the policy. Even documentation and online resources are not helpful. Can anyone suggest some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation:

- https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Batch+Metadata+Editing#BatchMetadataEditing-ImportFunction

That command is defined here:
https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace/config/launcher.xml#L199-L205

The launcher references [org.dspace.app.bulkedit.MetadataImport](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/bulkedit/MetadataImport.java)

Comment: Sir apologies, what i meant from batch import was batch import of items. 
 https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Importing+and+Exporting+Items+via+Simple+Archive+Format. It doesn't specify which class it uses and is very unclear.

Comment: I recommend that you close this question and create a new one that conveys your question.   Please note the documentation that you have already consulted.  The wiki page that you referenced does contain the class name: org.dspace.app.itemimport.ItemImport